# Can my Crouse-Hinds panel use type BRD breakers?

Tags: electrical-panel

Townhome built in the 80s. 200 amp panel with a note on the door stating type "BR and BRO" (not a typo) breakers are allowed. Have never seen type BRO. I have seen type BRD, some of which appear to have a different method of connection/metal clip on the end which connects with the center of the panel. Those cannot be physically installed without modification and I understand that this is not allowed.

However, I recently checked my panel and there are indeed a few type BRD breakers there. They are not original and were not modified by me. I once replaced a lot of breakers as they were covered in paint. I need to know if these are ok or do they need to be replaced by type BR? As with much of my electrical, I was burgled in 2020 and my panel and many circuits were messed with.

I have not yet looked at each type BRD breaker to see if they had been modified by someone else and am not sure if it would be obvious. Any electrical forensic  people out there who could comment?

Did a type BRO exist? Thanks so much.

Panel does not have an ID but has 16 total one inch spaces and an exterior main elsewhere on the building.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the inside of the panel and any labels on/in it.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the label on the inside of the panel please?

Comment: Notes on the door mean nothing.  What matters is the official label on the panel.  On the Crouse-Hinds panels this is a fairly complex document. Post a picture if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Eaton (Cutler Hammer) makes a BRO breaker that switches the neutral along with the hot. They aren't commonly used and are quite expensive. If your panel doesn't say you can use BRD breakers, they should be replaced with the BR breakers, also by Eaton. they are commonly available at most home stores and electrical supply stores.

Comment: Thank you very much. The "note on the door" is better described as a sticker